# average by group, removing current row

Tags: r, data.table

I want to compute group means of a variable but excluding the focal respondent:

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.table(id = 1:30, y = runif(30), grp = rep(1:3, each=10))
```

The first record (respondent) should have an average of... the second... and so on:

```
mean(dat[c==1, y][-1])
mean(dat[c==1, y][-2])
mean(dat[c==1, y][-3])
```

For the second group the same:

```
mean(dat[c==2, y][-1])
mean(dat[c==2, y][-2])
mean(dat[c==2, y][-3])
```

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
ex[, avg := mean(ex[, y][-.I]), by=grp]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I know I can do it this way: ```dat[, avg := (sum(y)-y)/(.N-1), by=c]```, but I would like to deal with the missing data.

Comment: Maybe, `sum(y,na.rm=TRUE)`?

Comment: I would need to adjust .N to estimate a valid average like when using mean(y, na.rm=TRUE)

Comment: I see. Then, how about using `(sum(!is.na(y))-1)` in the denominator?

Comment: If the current y is NA, the result would be NA... it should be the sum of the remaining valid y's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you're most of the way there and just need to account for `NA`'s:

```
dat[, avg := (sum(y, na.rm=T) - ifelse(is.na(y), 0, y)) / (sum(!is.na(y)) + is.na(y) - 1)
    , by = grp]
```

No double loops or extra memory required.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this solution:

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.table(id = 1:9, y = c(NA,runif(8)), grp = rep(1:3, each=3))

dat[, avg2 := sapply(seq_along(y),function(i) mean(y[-i],na.rm=T)), by=grp]

dat
#    id         y grp      avg2
# 1:  1        NA   1 0.3188163
# 2:  2 0.2655087   1 0.3721239
# 3:  3 0.3721239   1 0.2655087
# 4:  4 0.5728534   2 0.5549449
# 5:  5 0.9082078   2 0.3872676
# 6:  6 0.2016819   2 0.7405306
# 7:  7 0.8983897   3 0.8027365
# 8:  8 0.9446753   3 0.7795937
# 9:  9 0.6607978   3 0.9215325
```

Comment: this kind of a double (triple if you include the `by` loop) loop will become exponentially slow as the size of data increases

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, I think this does the job:

```
dat[,
  .(id, y2=rep(y, .N), id2=rep(id, .N), id3=rep(id, each=.N)), by=grp      
][
  !(id2 == id3),
  mean(y2), 
  by=.(id3, grp)
]
```

First step is to duplicate the whole group data for each id, and to mark which row we want to exclude from the mean.  Second step is to exclude the rows, and then group back by group/id.  Obviously this isn't super memory efficient, but should work so long as you're not memory constrained.

Comment: each respondent (row) should have a different value: the mean of all the values of the group except for that one of the current/focal respondent.

Comment: @sdaza, updated with a two step process that I think does what you want.

Comment: thanks @BrodieG, I thought there could be a simpler solution using data.table....

Comment: @sdaza, okay, the above should now reproduce your version, but again, your version with marat's modifications is still superior.